# Track download completed in php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, download

I i'm doing a shopping cart for selling digital products(songs).After sucessfull purchase it is sending a unique url to the buyer.they can download the song by clicking the url.

My problem is what if a customer fail to download the song completely(Due to some network problem or something else) how can i track it.i mean the customer clicks on the url then the download begins, how do i know if it is completed or not?

on going through google i found that the solution for this is use some flash or java aplet code. but i will be happy if i can handle it with php or jquery ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343418/browser-event-when-downloaded-file-is-saved-to-disk or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295576/ajax-jquery-finding-if-user-completed-the-download

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses a download manager like Akamai DLM, then you can hook Javascript into the DLM. If not, and you are hosting the download on your servers, you could have some process running that tracks the download request and detect it that way. If the download is hosted on a CDN and you are not using a DLM, your CDN provider may be able to provide a way to do this. It really depends on how you are providing your downloads.

Comment: I'm hosting the download files in my server and not using any DLM.And i'm looking for a track the download complete.I used to set some cockie methods.but it is not work at all.